# Refresh specific resource and it's events in Full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

To refresh the specific resource and its events I am trying the following steps:

1. Remove specific resource
2. Create specific Resource again and add its newly fetched all events

**Sample code**

```
var resourceA = calendar.getResourceById('2');

resourceA.remove(); // Remove resource 2

var res =
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Resource 2'
};

calendar.addResource(res); // To Add resource again

//Event creation

var evnt = [
    {
      resourceId : 2,
      start : "2021-09-22 00:30:00",
      end : "2021-09-22 01:30:00",
      title : "Event 1"
    },
    {
      resourceId : 2,
      start : "2021-09-22 02:30:00",
      end : "2021-09-22 03:30:00",
      title : "Event 2"
    }
];

calendar.addEventSource(evnt);  //Create events of resource 2
```

Now what happens is: when I create resource 2 again, previous events are not being removed. So then when I add events, duplicate events are showing.

Is there any way I can remove all events of resource 2 when I remove resource and fetch the events again? To be clear: not all the events of the calendar, just the ones from resource 2. Or if there is any better way please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you add the events for Resource 2 the first time? Were they together with all the other events, or were they in a separate event source? If they are in a separate event source then you could remove that source when you remove the resource.

Comment: But also, why do you need to re-add the events again when you add the resource? If you are using a dynamic event feed (e.g. from a URL or a callback function) then you could just run refetchEvents and it would fetch all the events for the calendar again, including the re-created resource. It all depends...we don't know enough about the rest of your calendar setup to give a useful answer, so please edit your question with more information. Thanks.